# Laurent series in various regions

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions, laurent-series

I have the question: "Find the Laurent series which represents the function

$$ 
f(z) = (z^2 - 1)/(z + 2)(z + 3)\
$$

in the regions

(i) $\mid z\mid < 2\ $

(ii) $ 2 < \mid z\mid < 3\ $

(iii) $\mid z\mid > 3\ $"

I can rewrite this function into partial fractions as:

$$
f(z) = 5/(z+2) - 10/(z+3)
$$

I understand that for part (ii) this is the region within the annulus.

I also know that I can  write:

$$
5/(z+2) = 5/2 \sum (-1)^n (z/2)^n $$ for $ \mid z\mid < 2\ $

$$
10/(z+3) = 10/3 \sum (-1)^n (z/3)^n $$ for $ \mid z\mid < 3\ $

I also know how to find the respective sums for $ \mid z\mid > 2\ $ and $ \mid z\mid > 3\ $ 
But I'm not at all sure how to combine these to get the answers for the whole function $f$, for parts (i), (ii) and (iii).

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) $|z| < 2$

$$\frac5{z+2}-\frac{10}{z+3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac52\left(\frac{z}2\right)^n-\frac{10}3\left(\frac{z}3\right)^n\right)$$

(ii) $2<|z|<3$
\begin{align*}
  & \frac{5}{z+2} - \frac{10}{z+3} \\
  =& \frac{5}{z} \frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{z}} - \frac{10}{3} \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{3}} \\
  =& -\frac{10}{3} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \left( \frac{z}{3} \right)^n + \frac{5}{z} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^n \\
  =& \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^{n + 1} \frac{10}{3} \left( \frac{z}{3} \right)^n + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n - 1} 5 \left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^n
\end{align*}

(iii) $|z|>3$

\begin{align*}
  & \frac{5}{z+2} - \frac{10}{z+3} \\
  =& \frac{5}{z} \frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{z}} - \frac{10}{z} \frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{z}} \\
  =& \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \left( 5 \left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^n - 10 \left( \frac{3}{z} \right)^n \right) \\
  =& \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n - 1} \left( 5 \left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^n - 10 \left( \frac{3}{z} \right)^n \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: The only issue I'm still having is for part (i): You use the sum version of 10/(z+3) even though it's only valid for mod(z) < 3, when the question wants the series for mod(z) < 2. Why is it OK to do this? (Similarly for part (iii) - you use the sum version of 5/(z+2) even though it's only valid for mod(z) > 2, and the question asks for the region mod(z) > 3)

Comment: (i) $|z| < 2 < 3$  
(iii) $|z| > 3 > 2$